# Error receiving broadcast intent wifi manager FTP Connection

Tags: android, multithreading, ftp

I'm coding an android application which is supposed to connect to a FTP Server. I'm trying to make the FTP connection automatic. For instance, if a user is connected to the wifi and disable wifi on his phone, and enable it later, i want the app to automatically reconnect to the ftp server. For that, i'm using a broadcast receiver which method onReceive is called whenever there is a CONNECTIVITY_ACTION. Here is the onReceive() method :

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if(intent == null)
        return;
    ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo ni = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    WifiManager wifiMgr = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    if(wifiMgr != null && wifiMgr.isWifiEnabled()){
        WifiInfo winfo = wifiMgr.getConnectionInfo();
        if(winfo.getNetworkId() == -1){
            connected = false;
        } else {
            connected = true;
        }
    } else{
        connected = false;
    }
    notifyStateToAll();
}
```

The notifyStateToAll(); function active the listeners by calling the function NetworkAvailable() if connected, and NetworkUnavailable() if not.

I have a listener is a thread that tries to connect to the FTP Server whenever connected is true. Here is the problem. When connected is true & my listener tries to connect, i get this error :

```
09-12 09:04:54.221 15834-15834/app.smartmonument.com.guide E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     Process: app.smartmonument.com.guide, PID: 15834
     java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE flg=0x4000010 bqHint=4 (has extras) } in app.smartmonument.com.guide.NetworkStateReceiver@fcd0242
         at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:1003)
         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
      Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
         at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1273)
         at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
         at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:137)
         at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
         at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
         at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:452)
         at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:884)
         at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient._connect(SocketClient.java:243)
         at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:202)
         at app.smartmonument.com.guide.FTPCreator.connect(FTPCreator.java:76)
         at app.smartmonument.com.guide.FTPThread.networkAvailable(FTPThread.java:81)
         at app.smartmonument.com.guide.NetworkStateReceiver.notifyState(NetworkStateReceiver.java:68)
         at app.smartmonument.com.guide.NetworkStateReceiver.notifyStateToAll(NetworkStateReceiver.java:60)
         at app.smartmonument.com.guide.NetworkStateReceiver.onReceive(NetworkStateReceiver.java:55)
         at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:993)
         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229) 
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

This error refers to the "ftp.connect()" of this method that is called when "connected == true" : The ftp object is a FTPClient() object.

```
@Override
public void networkAvailable(){
    try{
        ftp.connect();
        ftp.changeDir("/eiffel");
    } catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: NetworkOnMainThreadException. Please google.

Comment: @greenapps Well this is already in a thread. I don't understand why this error is happening.

Comment: We cannot see where you call networkAvailable(). We also cannot see what is 'ftp'.

Comment: `Here is the onReceive() method : ` ? I do not see an onReceive method.

Comment: I just edited my question

Comment: `The notifyStateToAll(); function active the listeners by calling the function NetworkAvailable() if connected, and NetworkUnavailable() if not.` We cannot see how you do that. Why so complicated code. Why dont you call directly `networkAvailable()` in onCreate() to show us the problem? And why not name that function connectToFtpServer() ?

Comment: `I have a listener is a thread that tries to connect to the FTP Server ` ?? Then you schould show us that code. How should we know what you are doing?